# Reading from a file into a matrix of booleans in java

Tags: java

I have a text file formatted like this:

```
5
true, false, true, false, false
true, false, true, true, true
false, false, false, false, true
true, true, false, true, true
false, false, false, true, false
```

and I want to read it to a matrix. 
Here's what i've managed to do so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tests {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("File Name: ");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = reader.nextLine();
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)));

        int size = file.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Size: " + size);

        boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[size][size];


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

                matrix[i][j] = file.nextBoolean();
            }

        }
        reader.close();
        file.close();
    }
}
```

However this gives me an error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1782)
    at tests.tests.main(tests.java:27)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the end of line characters before reading from the next line :

```
    int size = file.nextInt();
    file.nextLine(); // added
    System.out.println("Size: " + size);

    boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = file.nextBoolean();
        }
        file.nextLine(); // added
    }
```

Comment: @laker001 I made a small edit. You have to add 2 `nextLine()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You appears to want to use `,` as a delimiter instead of just space.

I suggest using

```
scanner.useDelimiter(",?\\s+");
```

to allow an optional `,` between values.